# How to pass information from inside sequence/property to the outside world

Tags: system-verilog

I have a `property` that is waiting for two different `sequence` to happen, as follows (the `sequence` and `property` are already simplified here):

```
sequence seq1;
  logic [3:0] a;
  @(posedge clk) (some_signal1 == 1, a = other_signal1); 
endsequence

sequence seq2;
  logic [3:0] b;
  @(posedge clk) (some_signal2 == 1, b = other_signal2); 
endsequence

property abc;
  seq1 ##[1:$] seq2;
endproperty
```

`some_signal1`,`some_signal2`, `other_signal1`, `other_signal2` are all RTL signals.

My question:
When the `property abc` is passed or covered, I want to know the corresponding `other_signal1` and `other_signal2` sampled in the sequences. How can I access those signals values?

I am thinking to hierarchically access the `sequence` local variables, such as `seq1.a` or `seq2.b`. But these are not allowed, as they are locals.

Declaring those variables as formal argument also does not help, because formal argument can not be assigned in the LHS.

My intention is that I am going to use those signals for other purpose, i.e.:

```
cover property (abc) begin
  // grab seq1.a and seq2.b, and do some other tasks
end
```

Comment: I think, assertions/properties/sequences are made for verification of design, not to assignment of data. For assignment, you should use procedural blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of 3 things on the right of the comma inside the `( , )`:

- an assignment (to a local variable)
- increment or decrement
- call a tasks, task method, void function, void function method or system task.

(see [IEEE1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), 16.11 Calling subroutines on match of a sequence)

A task call is the key to this. You can assign to variables outside the task scope within a task called from within the sequence:

```
  sequence seq1;
    @(posedge clk) (some_signal1 == 1, assign_a(other_signal1)); 
  endsequence

  sequence seq2;
    @(posedge clk) (some_signal2 == 1, assign_b(other_signal2)); 
  endsequence

  property abc;
    seq1 ##[1:$] seq2;
  endproperty

  cover property (abc) 
    $display("a= %d, b= %d", a , b);

  task assign_a(input int i);
    a = i;
  endtask

  task assign_b(input int i);
    b = i;
  endtask
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/akw

Comment: Since property is automatic, by using simple task assignment, `a` will be overwritten whenever another `seq1` fired off while the previous thread had not completed. In this sense we should keep multiple record of `a`'s (`a` must be automatic). I don't think simple local assignment like that can work (as it will be overwritten when new thread comes in).

Comment: @AldoT I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't you have the same problem with your original code (if it were legal); your original code assigns to `a` and `b` as does mine. The task consumes no time and has no local variables, so I don't understand why the automatic/static distinction is important.

Comment: in your example, `other_signal1` and `other_signal2` are constant, so you won't see any issue. What if those signal changes in time? Here is counter example http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5HdE to clarify my problem.

Comment: @AldoTThanks for your example - I understand what you meant, now. Doesn't your original (non-working) idea not suffer from the same problem? If you want to "grab" the value of the local variables `a` and `b` then you need to store them in some way that accounts for the fact that there may be multiple threads. So, to solve this problem, could you perhaps design a class that manages it? It would have a method called from within the `assign_` task that added the new value to some kind of dynamic data structure that the rest of the code could then access when required?

Comment: My original code is just to express my intention. It doesn't work. I thought there is some built-in way in sequence to achieve that. If not, then I will need to design a class as you mentioned.